# Simpler alternative for $\int\frac{dx}{2\sin x+3\cos x+7}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Find
$$\int\frac{dx}{2\sin{x}+3\cos{x}+7}$$
My attempt:
$$I= \int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{13}\sin{\left(x+\theta\right)}+{7}}$$
where $\sin{\theta}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{13}}$.
Then, subsititute
$$t = \tan{\frac{y}{2}}$$where
$y=x +\theta$.

But, I think there is a simpler solution than above substitution. Would you help me?

Comment: Do you mean you want to let $t=\tan y/2$?

Comment: @Hussien Mohamed: Using the formulas $\sin(x)=2\sin(x/2)\cos (x/2)$ and $\cos(x)=\cos^2(x/2)-\sin^2(x/2)$ one can transform your integral as $I=\int\frac{dt}{4t^2+4t+10}$, where $t=\tan(x/2)$. This enables you to finish the integration.

Comment: Look at the solution to the integral here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+dx%2F(2sinx%2B3cosx%2B7). Do you think there can be a simple set of steps that could lead to that kind of answer?

Comment: @Marian G That is the same solution i have mentioned

Comment: @Hussien Mohamed: I'm somewhat confused from your approach.

Answer (score 3):

Below is an alternative to the half-angle substitution

\begin{align}
&\int\frac{1}{2\sin x+3\cos x+7}\ dx\\
=& \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{13}\sin y +7}\ dy
=\int \frac{\sec^2 y \ (\sqrt{13}\sin y+7)}{\sec^2y\ (\sqrt{13}\sin y+7)^2} \ dy\\
=& \int \frac{\sqrt{13}\sec y \tan y + 7\sec^2 y}{13\tan^2 y + 49 \sec^2 y + 7\sqrt{13} \sec y \tan y} \ dy\\
=&\int \frac{d(\sqrt{13}\sec y+7\tan y)}{(\sqrt{13}\sec y+7\tan y)^2 +36}
=\frac16 \tan^{-1}\frac {\sqrt{13}\sec y+7\tan y}6\\
= &\ \frac16 \tan^{-1}\frac {13\sec x +7(2\tan x+3)}{6(2-3\tan x)}
\end{align}

Comment: What is the formula for $y$?

Comment: @gist076923 - same as OP’s $y=x+\theta$